# Set class property of an instance within class method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop

My Objective is:

Using MATLAB, set the property value within one class method, and the property values are different between instances.

My Problem is:

1. When using SET in the class method, I will change the property value of all instances of this class, which is not what I want. I only want to change the property value of this instance.
2. About the dynamic property: I think it's used to create a unique property of the instance instead of setting the unique value of a general class property, is that right?

Code example:

```
classdef Storage

    properties
      tree =  containers.Map('KeyType','int32', 'ValueType','any')
    end

    methods        

    function obj = set_tree(obj,period, value)
        obj.tree(period) = value;
    end

    end

end
```

When setting the value using this method:

```
   st1 = Storage();
   st2 = Storage();

   st1 = st1.set_tree(10,1);
   st2 = st2.set_tree(10,2);
```

Right now, the value set to `st2.tree(10)` will override the value set to `st1.tree(10)`, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you show us a code example?

Comment: Hi, I just edited it. Thank you!

Comment: @gnovice Sorry to bother again...can you help me run the sample code in my question now? it seems that container.map property will behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is caused by setting a [handle class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) object as a [default value](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html#brqy3km-10) for a class property. [The relevant documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-containing-objects.html#bu008rz-1) says this:

> MATLAB® evaluates property default values only once when loading the class. MATLAB does not reevaluate the assignment each time you create an object of that class. If you assign an object as a default property value in the class definition, MATLAB calls the constructor for that object only once when loading the class.

So, for your `Storage` class above, *all* of your instances will be using the same default [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) object stored in the `tree` property. And since the `containers.Map` class is a subclass of the [`handle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html) class it has reference behavior, which means the copies of the object will all point to the same underlying key/value map. If you want independent objects for each instance, you can initialize  the `tree` property in the constructor:

```
classdef Storage

  properties
    tree
  end

  methods
    function obj = Storage()
      obj.tree = containers.Map('KeyType','int32', 'ValueType','any');
    end
    function obj = set_tree(obj, value, period)
      obj.tree(period) = value;
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: @WenbinLiu: Happy to help! Next time you have a question, remember to add as much detail about the code as possible right from the start. It'll get you quicker answers. Also, don't forget that you can [mark answers as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) when they've solved your problem.

Comment: Will do next time! Thanks!

Comment: Note that the reason this is an issue here is that `containers.Map` is a handle class, so it's the same instance that's referenced in all instances of the class. If you were using a struct, this wouldn't happen.